# TopCoder Alogirithm System Test Failure

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I am doing a problem from Top-Coder.The problem statement is-

> One day, Jamie noticed that many English words only use the letters A
>   and B. Examples of such words include "AB" (short for abdominal),
>   "BAA" (the noise a sheep makes), "AA" (a type of lava), and "ABBA" (a
>   Swedish pop sensation).
>
> Inspired by this observation, Jamie created a simple game. You are
>   given two Strings: initial and target. The goal of the game is to find
>   a sequence of valid moves that will change initial into target. There
>   are two types of valid moves:
>
> Add the letter A to the end of the string. Reverse the string and then
>   add the letter B to the end of the string. Return "Possible" (quotes
>   for clarity) if there is a sequence of valid moves that will change
>   initial into target. Otherwise, return "Impossible".

Below is my solution of the problem which passed all the tests in the Panel but failed in system test.But,I did not get any specific information about which test case failed.Please check if my code will not work in some scenario.

```
class ABBA
{
public string canObtain(string initial,string target)
{
    string s = "Impossible";

            if (initial.Length > target.Length)
                return "Impossible";

            if (initial.Equals(target))
                return "Possible";

            if (CheckFirstWay(target,initial))
            {
                s=canObtain(initial+"A",target);
            }
            if (s.Equals("Impossible") && CheckSecondWay(target,initial))
            {
                s=canObtain(ReverseStringDirect(initial) + "B",target);
            }

            return s;
}
   public static string ReverseStringDirect(string s)
        {
            char[] array = new char[s.Length];
            int forward = 0;
            for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                array[forward++] = s[i];
            }
            return new string(array);
        }

        private static bool CheckSecondWay(string final, string initial)
        {
            if (final.Contains(ReverseStringDirect(initial) + "B") || final.Contains("B"+initial))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static bool CheckFirstWay(string final1, string initial)
        {
            if (final1.Contains(initial + "A") || final1.Contains(ReverseStringDirect(initial+"A")))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: Since your solution is already partially working, and this is a TopCoder question, you might get better feedback on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please check the answer..test cases are provided there.

Comment: If it helped please select the answer. It might help future users.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on which test failed by following procedure,

> 1. Go to the specified room.
> 2. Open the problem.
> 3. Compile.
> 4. Submit it.
> 5. Then go to run system test.
> 6. you will see the error test there.

OR

> 1. Select the match from [here](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=round_overview&rd=16883).
> 2. Then in the page as shown you will see set of blue coders and red coders who topped the match.
> 3. Select any one player as per your division. `[.]` --> this logo beside name.
> 4. Then check their solution you will see those tests.

**Here are the [test cases](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_solution&rm=326648&rd=16512&pm=13918&cr=22932442)..check it out.**

You have to type system tests here. You can check the image below. Image credit : Google

[image]

Comment: Did you find the test now?

Comment: I found the test cases at https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_solution&cr=22664154&rd=16512&pm=13922 but is there any way I can figure out which test case failed for me?

Comment: One thing I notice that is different is in the question for practice its written that "Reverse the string and then add the letter B to the end of the string" while the contest has the constraint as "Add the letter B to the end of the string and then reverse the entire string."

Comment: @SomeshDhal.: Yes you can..submit it and run system test. It wil tell you which test case you failed by showing red cross mark beside taht test case.

Comment: @SomeshDhal.: Please post the proepr code..otherwise it's meaningless. Your code is not following the rule of C# code submission in topcoder. Compile first . Then check.

Comment: I did as above.The code compiled successfully. After that the system test failed without giving any proper test case.

Comment: Posted the proper code from Top Coder. In practice arena I am not getting the list of test cases that are run as part of system test.It just shows system test failed.

Comment: @SomeshDhal.: Are you using webarena or appletarea?

Comment: @SomeshDhal.: I guess you are using web arena..as a result you are not able to see the tests on which you failed.

Comment: Yes,I was trying with web arena.I tried the same with appletarea,but not able to find the same practice problem there.Thanks,Anyway.

Comment: I found the same room in arena.I compiled and did batch test.Every test passed.But  I do not see a system test option there.Please help if I am missing something.

Comment: @SomeshDhal.: Look you did batch test...and all.Then submit it. A popup appears showing that "You have successfully submitted...points". Then you close that window. You will see the window from where you have to choose problems.. Just look for Run for system test option there. You will get it.

Comment: @SomeshDhal.: check the answer.